# Limit of a function of two variables

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $\displaystyle f(x,y) = \frac{x^2  y}{x^4 + y^2}$

Does this function have a limit when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

Comment: See my (closely) related answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/202608/28900).

Comment: Thank you. I worked it out and found that the limit dne but my tutor said that it did...

Comment: My answer there (and the comments below it) actually show you how to rigorously prove that the limit doesn't exist. Your tutor is mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Set first $x=\sqrt{y}$ for $y>0$, and then $x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x,x^2)=\frac{1}{2}\not=0=\lim_{x\to0}f(x,0)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^2=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, where $-\pi/2\le \theta\le \pi/2$. Then our function is equal to $\cos\theta\sin\theta$. In particular, its values for $r$ near $0$ depend on the value of $\theta$.